# SparkContext error running in sbt: There is already an RpcEndpoint called LocalBackendEndpoint

Tags: apache-spark

A spark testcase is working when run within Intellij but failing through `sbt test`.

The failure is in creating the `SparkContext` during the `netty` connection server establishment:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "SamplingTest", new SparkConf())
```

Error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is already an RpcEndpoint called LocalBackendEndpoint` .  Here is the stacktrace:

```
[info] SamplingSpec:
[info] Factorization
[info] - should factorize *** FAILED *** (1 second, 957 milliseconds)
[info]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is already an RpcEndpoint called LocalBackendEndpoint
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.registerRpcEndpoint(Dispatcher.scala:65)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.setupEndpoint(NettyRpcEnv.scala:136)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend.start(LocalBackend.scala:126)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
[info]   at org.vz.datasci.spark.ml.SamplingSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SamplingSpec.scala:13)
```

There is only one SparkContext being created and ssh to the local host works.  What else should be considered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same errors because my tests were running in parrallel.

In my build.sbt, I added :

> parallelExecution in Test := false

Not sure if it is the best solution, but it solved it.

Comment: ah! I had not considered that!  Will try it out. I am going to upvote - even if that does not solve my issue it is a good thing to keep in mind.  btw does it *default* to `parallelExecution` ?  I would have thought sequential would have been in play unless specified otherwise.

Comment: According to the official doc : "By default, sbt executes tasks in parallel" . And it considers each test as a task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot java application. you can do it as ..

JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, false), classes);

Comment: Where to write this ? In "@SpringBootApplication" ??